# Ionic - show radio buttons in popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have home state in my app

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    cache: false,
    controller: 'HomeCtrl as home',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
})
```

My home controller

```
angular
   .module('home')
   .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate', '$ionicLoading',];

function HomeCtrl($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicLoading){
     var vm = this;
     vm.sortCriteria = 'Price';
     vm.showSortPopup = showSortPopup;
     return vm;

     function showSortPopup(){
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Sort',
            templateUrl : 'home/sort.html',
            scope : vm,
            buttons: [
                { text: 'Cancel'},
                {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function(e) {
                        console.log(vm.sortCriteria);
                    }
                },
            ]

        });
    }
}
```

sort.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio ng-model="home.sortCriteria" ng-value="'Price'">Price</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="home.sortCriteria" ng-value="'Distance'">Distance</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

As my `sortCriteria` is not part of `$scope` how do I bind it to radio buttons in my popup?

Comment: did you try to call it as a part of the `HomeCtrl` ?? like this
`HomeCtrl.sortCriteria`

Comment: I tried to call it as `home.HomeCtrl` but that did not work.

Comment: without home just `HomeCtrl.sortCriteria`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason why you are using vm rather than a $scope?
I would rather try to use the $scope as follows:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup) {

//            var vm = this;
            $scope.sortCriteria = 'Price';
            $scope.showSortPopup = showSortPopup;
//            return vm;

            function showSortPopup() {
                var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                    title: 'Sort',
                    templateUrl: 'home/sort.html',
                    scope: $scope,
                    buttons: [
                        {text: 'Cancel'},
                        {
                            text: 'Ok',
                            type: 'button-positive',
                            onTap: function (e) {
                                console.log($scope.sortCriteria);
                            }
                        },
                    ]

                });

            }
        })
```

And update sort.html as follows:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio ng-model="sortCriteria" ng-value="'Price'">Price</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="sortCriteria" ng-value="'Distance'">Distance</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The radio buttons are specific to that view and not part of $scope